# Function returning None type list instead of nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using list comprehension to filter out some words from an existing list and then want to return that list if its length is greater than three.

I've done this but rather than go to the else statement and not return anything it is returning a None value. Firstly, why is it returning a None value, and is there a way to not return anything? The code below recreates this output.

```
new_list = ['have', 'to', 'deal', 'with', 'the', 'rat', 'can', 't', 'have', 'it']

def processing_text(tweetobj):
    filtered_words = [word for word in new_list if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
    if len(filtered_words) > 3:
        return (filtered_words)
    else:
        pass

print (processing_text(new_list))
```

Comment: What should be anything? What you could do is check the output and not print in case is None.

Comment: Also to note you are using one parameter but a different variable inside.

Comment: A Python function always returns one value. If you use `return x` explicitly, it returns `x`. Otherwise, it returns `None`.

Comment: *is there a way to not return anything?* - so what would be the value of `x` after doing `x = func()`?

Comment: `None` IS the python object meaning "nothing".  But in your case, it would be better to return an empty list so the return values are consistent - if a function returns a given type in some conditions, it should return a similar (compatible) type for other conditions. And it's the calling code's duty to check what it gets as result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the array `filtered_words` is empty after the list-comprehension, so the function does not return anything (enters the `else` clause and simply passes). As such, the function returns `None`, so printing the return value shows `None`. **In this case, `None` means nothing.**

Your `else` clause is redundant:

```
def processing_text(tweetobj):
    filtered_words = [word for word in new_list if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
    if len(filtered_words) > 3:
        return (filtered_words)
```

---

```
>>> def foo():
...     1
... 
>>> x = foo()
>>> x
>>> x == None
True
>>>
```

Comment: yes, I wanted to not return anything if the list is less than three

Comment: This is what you are doing. The function will always return `None` when you do not specify a return value.

Comment: Its currently returning None. I mean is it possible to not return anything at all, as if breaking out of the function

Comment: @user1365234 nope

Comment: There is the alternative of throwing an exception. Then, technically, the function does not return, but of course, the exception would have to be caught.

Answer (score -2):

You could return an empty string:

```
def processing_text(tweetobj):
    filtered_words = [word for word in tweetobj if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
    if len(filtered_words) > 3:
        return (filtered_words)
    return ''
```

Comment: How is an empty string better than `None` ??? The function should either return `None` or (preferably IMHO) an empty list.

Comment: The OP was printing the return value from the function and didn't want to see `None`.